# Numbers change inside variables for powershell

Tags: powershell, types, number-formatting

I am literally just trying to convert a string with week and day information to numbers and store it as variable, yet something really funky is happening, as of now, I have tested this behavior in 4 PCs, and in Powershell 5 and 7 its happening all over the place.

```
$UP_Down = "6w0d"

[int]$weeks = if ($Up_Down -match "w"){$Up_Down[$($Up_Down.IndexOf('w')-1)]}Else{0}

[int]$days = if ($Up_Down -match "d"){$Up_Down[$Up_Down.IndexOf('d')-1]}Else{0}

[int]$totaldays = (7 * $weeks) + $days
```

Now the data from the initial variable is obviously **6 weeks** and **0 days** to which I have to convert to **42 Total days** (this is just an example, its happening regardless of combination)

However the following is the Funky results I get which I have elaborated by `Write-Output`

```
Weeks If statement results by itself 6
Weeks variable results 54
days If statement results by itself 0
days variable results  48
totaldays variable results are 426
```

The problem occurs regardless of what numeric datatype I use

Ironically the Variables have the correct value if i DO NOT assign datatype to them, **BUT** ,

the moment it hits `(7*$weeks)` even IF the `$weeks` is correct the value outputted **426**, and remember no [int]etc anywhere

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: will the input data _always_ be structured as shown? the Answer i posted presumes so, but `mklement0` pointed out that your code implies that the data might be an of `3w4d`, `1w`, or `3d` ... and my Answer will fail miserably with the 2nd and 3rd formats. **_please let me know so that i can remove the Answer if the inputs might be like the 2nd or 3rd above._**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are not converting the number inside the string `"6"` to the number 6, but the character `'6'` to its value according to the underlying character encoding scheme that is 54 in the case of ASCII. Same with the day: `'0'` has a value of 48. 7 * 54 + 48 = 426.

See the difference:

```bsh
PS C:\Users\name> [int]"6"[0]
54
PS C:\Users\name> [int]"6"
6
```

When extracting an element of the string through indexing with `[0]` you get a character instead of a string of length 1. A cast to `int` will then return the ASCII value of this character.

Comment: That's definitely better and technically correct, though it wouldn't hurt to note that .NET strings use a form of _Unicode_ encoding, specifically UTF-16; that is, a .NET string is always composed of UTF-16 _code units_. These units have a [Unicode] _code point_, not an "ASCII value". Saying "will then return the ASCII value" is somewhat misleading, because that is only true if the input character happens to fall in the ASCII _subrange_ of Unicode (which is certainly true for `6`, but wouldn't be true for `€`, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

You're *indexing* (`[...]`) into string `$Up_Down`, which means **you're returning a *single character*, i.e. a `[char]` ([`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char)) instance**.

**Casting a `[char]` to `[int]` yields its *Unicode code point*** ("ASCII value"), *not* the digit that the character happens to represent.

For instance, the *character* `6` is Unicode character DIGIT SIX with code point [`U+0036`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/36); `0036` is the hexadecimal form of the numeric code point, and the decimal form of hexadecimal `0x36` is `54`.

```
PS> [int] "6w0d"[0]
54 # !! Same as: [int] [char] "6"
```

To interpret the character as a *digit*, **you need an *intermediate `[string]` cast***:

```
PS> [int] [string] "6w0d"[0]
6   # OK - a string is parsed as expected; same as: [int] "6"
```

If you cast a *string* rather than `char` to `[int]`, PowerShell effectively calls [`System.Int32.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32.Parse) behind the scenes as follows: `[int]::Parse($string, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`.

Note that **PowerShell has *no* `char` *literals*** - unlike in C#, `'...'` quoting *also* produces *strings* (verbatim ones), and `[int] '6'` yields integer `6`, just like `[int] "6"` does.

Conversely, you need an explicit `[char]` cast to convert a single-character string literal to a `[char]`; e.g., `[char] '6'`; a multi-character string would cause the cast to *fail*.

---

The solution in the context of your command:

```
[int]$weeks = if ($Up_Down -match "w"){[string] $Up_Down[$Up_Down.IndexOf('w')-1]} Else {0}

[int]$days = if ($Up_Down -match "d"){[string] $Up_Down[$Up_Down.IndexOf('d')-1]} Else {0}
```

However, **I suggest solving the problem differently**:

```
[int] $totalDays = 0
if ($UP_Down -match '^(?:(?<weeks>\d+)w)?(?:(?<days>\d+)d)?$') {
  [int] $weeks, [int] $days = $Matches.weeks, $Matches.days
  $totalDays = 7 * $weeks + $days
} # else: string wasn't in expected format.
```

Answer (score 1):

others have shown you why the problem hit you, so this is just an alternate way to get the total day count. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- fakes reading in a text file of Week/Day codes
  when ready to use real data, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and use `Get-Content`.
- iterates thru the list
- splits on the `w`
- trims away the trailing `d`
- assigns the resulting strings to the two `[int]` variables on the left of the `=`
  this forces the two number *strings* to become number *objects*.
- calcs the total days
- displays the week/day code, week count, day count, and total days

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a list of week/day codes
#    in real life use Get-Content
$WD_List = @'
6w0d
3w3d
0w1d
66w6d
9w1d
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a list of week/day codes

foreach ($WL_Item in $WD_List)
    {
    [int]$WeekCount, [int]$DayCount = $WL_Item.Split('w').TrimEnd('d')
    $TotalDays = ($WeekCount * 7) + $DayCount


    $WL_Item
    $WeekCount
    $DayCount
    $TotalDays
    '=' * 20
    }
```

the output ...

```
6w0d
6
0
42
====================
3w3d
3
3
24
====================
0w1d
0
1
1
====================
66w6d
66
6
468
====================
9w1d
9
1
64
====================
```

Comment: Note that the OP's code is written so that it can deal with either component being missing; your solution would malfunction with an input string such as `'3d'` for instance.